# Is it possible to use each with present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple, present-simple

> He has written to me for a long time and **each time** I **have received** his letter, I have felt  happy.
>   He has written to me for a long time and **each time** I **receive** his letter, I feel happy.
>   He has written to me for a long time and **each time** I **received** his letter, I felt happy.

Is it possible to use each with present perfect?  Are all these sentences valid?

Does the last sentence mean that my friend stopped recently writing to me?

Comment: Regardless of the bolded parts, you cannot say "He has written to me for a long time", because *for a long time* refers to the past. For example, "I have not been to Disneyland *for a long time*" just refers to the time from somewhere in the past up to now. But I could now (present time) go there.

Comment: Are you sure, present perfect begins in the past and continues up to now or recently stopped